# More open sets or more closed sets in a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Are there more open sets or more closed sets? I think that there are as many open sets as closed ones.

Comment: For every open set $U \subset X$, $X - U$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct; there is a bijection between the set of open subsets of $X$ and the set of closed subsets of $X$, 
$$U\longleftrightarrow X-U,$$
because by definition a set $S\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $X-S$ is open. Because there is a bijection between the set of open subsets and the set of closed subsets, they have the same cardinality.